# How to link a js file when editing a plugin in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am using Grails 2.5.6. I am editing spring-security-plugin. 
My spring-security-plugin version is 2.0-RC5. I need to link a
javascript file in my view. But it shows file not found. Here are my attepmts below:

in my view >>>

```
<head>
<title>Royal Page</title>
<link href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'common.css')}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

my directory structure >>>

[image]